# How to set an on start handler for flask app.run()

Tags: python, flask

I haven't found a way to set a handler to detect when a flask server is already running. Consider the following code snippet:

```
import flask
import requests

def on_start():
    # send a request to the server, it's safe to do so
    # because we know it's already running
    r = requests.get("http://localhost:1234")
    print(r.text) # hello world

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "hello world"
app.run(port=1234, host="localhost", on_start=on_start)
```

The last line fails because `on_start` is not an argument of `run`, but hopefully you get the idea of what I'm trying to do. How can I do it?

Answer (score -3):

What you can do is wrap the function that you want to kick off with `before_first_request` decorator as found here ==> http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.before_first_request

However, it won't get kicked off until someone makes a request to the server but you can do something like this:

```
import requests
import threading
import time
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.before_first_request
def activate_job():
    def run_job():
        while True:
            print("Run recurring task")
            time.sleep(3)

    thread = threading.Thread(target=run_job)
    thread.start()

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"


def start_runner():
    def start_loop():
        not_started = True
        while not_started:
            print('In start loop')
            try:
                r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/')
                if r.status_code == 200:
                    print('Server started, quiting start_loop')
                    not_started = False
                print(r.status_code)
            except:
                print('Server not yet started')
            time.sleep(2)

    print('Started runner')
    thread = threading.Thread(target=start_loop)
    thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_runner()
    app.run()
```

Details & Source via Google-fu: https://networklore.com/start-task-with-flask/

Comment: That won't work for me, because I'm actually running a while loop with a try except block to try to run the server first on port 5000, and then try 5001 if 5000 is already used, and so on until one port works. The reason why I need the on_start handler is so I know which port it ended up using. Having another thread sending request to port 5000 will assume that the server is already running even if that's the port used by another server.

Comment: It's that kind of information that would have been helpful to know beforehand.  Perhaps it's a good idea to amend your original description with that tidbit of information.  Also, post relevant code... thanks.